# How to get a list (scan) of all available Wi-Fi networks/APs via ADB without root?

Tags: wi-fi, adb

**Non-root solutions only.**
I found a bunch of questions and answers on how to connect to specific WiFi manually, but surprisingly none about gathering network info (without requiring root or some custom packages/apps). I don't think there is legit aircrack-ng for Android, all I've seen are some shady ports and regardless, it will require root.

What I want is a built-in way to list detected networks/APS (including placeholder entries for hidden) via default ADB.

Comment: You can call o  WifiManager.startScan()

adb shell su 0 service call wifi 11

Comment: I already said I dont have root

Comment: Termux has a package that can retrieve the Wifi list from the last Wifi scan:https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-wifi-scaninfo

Comment: @Robert thats an API not package